# bcrypt very slow on nodejs server

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I have the following code in my `test.js` file:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { performance } = require("perf_hooks");

let hash = "$2b$20$v38KOyF2WSaJI/wcxSKN6u1iyvjfOu.Tjs3QHKCW2O4nCt0rTUgMu";
let password = "7!E:J|8yvGw$v]xXfKngkUAw3]EQ?B";

async function checkPassword() {
  let t = performance.now();
  if (await bcrypt.compare(password, hash)) {
    console.log("Passed! ", performance.now() - t);
  } else {
    console.log("Failed! ", performance.now() - t);
  }
}

checkPassword();
```

Then I run `node test.js`

The outputs I'm getting are:

```
Passed!  59178.30090880394          < for a correct password
Failed!  59386.33465099335          < for an incorrect password
```

That is nearly a minute for a basic check! **Is this the expected result?**

My package.json is using:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
  ...
```

I don't get any errors in the console, everything is completing correctly. The password I'm hashing is

```
7!E:J|8yvGw$v]xXfKngkUAw3]EQ?B
```

Is that just too long? I don't entirely understand how `bcrypt` works, in case that isn't obvious!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
$2b$20$v38KOyF2WSaJI/wcxSKN6u1iyvjfOu.Tjs3QHKCW2O4nCt0rTUgMu
```

That means:

- **Version**: 2b
- **Cost factor**: 20

## ***COST FACTOR 20***

A cost factor of 12 takes about 250 ms on current hardware.

| Cost | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 250 ms |
| 13 | 500 ms |
| 14 | 1 s |
| 15 | 2 s |
| 16 | 4 s |
| 17 | 8 s |
| 18 | 16 s |
| 19 | 32 s |
| 20 | 54 s |